# How to copy script files from src to dist using webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I am new to webpack and attempting to learn it. I have been trying to copy my vendor js files and custom jquery scripts from src to dist using webpack. I have tried but I couldn't find any way.

So this is how my folder structure is:

- Project_root_folder

  - node_modules/
  - package.json
  - src/
  - app/

    - app.js
  - img/

    - img1.png
  - css/

    - main.scss
  - js/

    - custom_slick.js
    - main.js
    - plugins/
    - jquery.min.js
    - slick.min.js
  - index.pug
  - about.pug
  - contact.pug
  - dist/
  - webpack.config.js

My webpack.config file

```
        var path = require("path"),
        src = path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
        dist = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        webpack = require("webpack"),
        HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin"),
        HtmlWebpackPugPlugin = require('html-webpack-pug-plugin'),
        ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin"),

        extractPlugin = new ExtractTextPlugin({
          filename: "css/main.css"
        });

    module.exports = {
      entry: src + "/app/app.js",
      output: {
        path: dist,
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/"
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
        {                                                                               //Convert .pug to .html
          test: /\.pug$/,
          loaders: ['file-loader?name=[name].html', 'pug-html-loader?pretty&exports=false']
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,                                   //convert .scss to .css
          use: extractPlugin.extract({
            use: ["css-loader", "sass-loader?minimize=true"]
          })
        },
        {
          test: /..\js\$\.js$/,                   // move all .js files in js folder
          use: [
            {
              loader: "file-loader",
              options: {
                name: "[name].js",
                outputPath: "js/"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /..\js\plugins\.js$/,
          use: [
                 {
                    loader: "file-loader",
                    options: {
                    name: "js/plugins/[name].js",
                    outputPath: "js/plugins/"
                    }
                 }
              ]
          }
        ]
      },
      plugins: [
        extractPlugin
      ]
    }
```

App.js file

```
import '../css/main.scss';

require.context('../js/', true, /\.js$/);                 //require all js files in js folder
require.context('../js/plugins/', true, /\.js$/);        // all js files in plugins folder which is inside js folder

function requirAll (r) { r.keys().forEach(r); }
requireAll(require.context('../', true, /\.pug$/));
```

Also when I run this config file, I noticed that only the script files with a suffix "-js" get copied and not any other js files included in js/ folder for example filename "main.js" doesn't get copied but if it were named "main-js.js" then it gets copied into my dist folder, and I am unable to copyfiles from plugins/ folder. I am unable to understand this.

I have tried every possible solution I could come across over Stack Overflow, GitHub and similar websites but none were helpful. Also I found webpack to be extremely confusing. Before moving to webpack, I had been using Gulp which I found a lot more helpful. I came across webpack and want to learn it but I am finding it extremely difficult.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use [Copy Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin) in order to copy files between folders.

I'm not sure the reason why you want to copy js files, webpack works like a tree dependency solver, so it should get an entry point (of the tree) and create a bundle that has the entire tree of dependencies.

Comment: Well what i am trying to achieve is this... writing funcitonalities using jquery library... and i dont wanna bundle it inside bundle.js... i simply wanna keep each of these js files separate. So thats the reason why i simply wanna to copy the js files from src to dist folder.

Comment: I tried using this but i get some weird folder structure inside my dist folder. So this is what i did in my config file:                
   copyWebpackPlugin = new copyPlugin([
      {from: "src/js/*", to: "js/"}
    ]) my dist/ contains > dist/js/src/js/ (all my js files from src/js/)

Comment: It always relative to the `output.path` filed.

Comment: You can specify that jQuery is an `external` file and webpack won't bundle it. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

Comment: well its not just jquery... i write many other js code which i dont want bundled. when developing, i want all my js files(functionality js code) to be copied into my production folder i.e dist/. This is much simpler with gulp but webpack is making it touch to get this done.

Comment: I am really getting stuck with my development. Having made several attempt, i couldnt finde any helpful solution to this problem. All i wanna do is not bundle my js code in bundle.js. If i am writing my react code for e.g and have multiple jquery custom files, few plugin files, i jsut wanna keep them separate, all my react code can be bundled, but all my other js files need to remain separate... i dont want them bundled... Please help.. Its really consuming a lot of my time and i am unable to proceed ahead...

Comment: If you are "require"ing or "import"ing them you can specify to webpack that those files gonna be on the global, and your are the responsible to supply it.
You can do that with specifying that  `jquery` is an *external*, https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

Comment: so can i also specify to webpack that all my other js files i.e all my .js files in my js/ folder, are global since i dont wanna bundle them in bundle.js? I will try this out. I really hope this helps coz i had been struggling a lot with this... wanna move ahead in my webpack learning.

Comment: would it possible for you to send me a config file with such settings? It would be of great help. Appreciate your response... Thanks...

Comment: There is no any good reason to "expose" your code on external (global) env.
It usually good practice for libs etc.
What is the reason for trying to not bundle your code?

Comment: Well what i prefer doing is: so i am coding some navigation functionality, so i like to keep my modules separately instead of bundling. Bundling everything into one file is absolutely fine when u have a 
SPA. But in case of Multi-page Website, i would prefer keeping my modules separately rather then bundle all my js into 1 file. Say if your home page requires only 4 or 5 js files out of say 20, then y bundle? and it's a bad practice. So thats y. Please help. I was excited about webpack but now i am loosing interest which might stop me from learning react since u need webpack for react...

Comment: And i feel that keeping modules separately is more cleaner way of coding instead of bundling everything into one. Exception might be an SPA but again if you r using react for coding an SPA, then keeping react code and other js code separately is what i would prefer doing.

Comment: I have a chrome extension. There is no entry point that will assist with the dependency tree.